# MySQL database, specially views restore using php

Tags: mysql, database-restore

I wanted to backup, then restore a database, and haven't found much view restore example. I am not thinking about using mysqldump, instead of PHP. Using php code, I can backup the database schema, data, and views into a flat file.

after then I use command

```
'mysql -u uid -ppwd databasename < my.sql'
```

to restore the database, everything looks good except a couple of views get lost because they are referencing other view which has not been created so far. For tables, they are different and can be restored by disabling the FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS and some other variables.  How about view? Is there similar system variable can be used to restore the database? or I have to put those views in correct order?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: In instances where I've done this, I've just had to ensure the views are created in the correct order.  There may be a better way, it's just that  it's always seemed easier to just correct the insert instead (esp as it's usually when syncing rather than a restore)

Comment: Thank you Simon for your nice comments. Yes, I probably will do the same thing if I can not get a better way :).